# Division by following row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe which looks like this

```
Date    |index_numer
26/08/17|200
27/08/17|300
28/08/17|400
29/08/17|100
30/08/17|150
01/09/17|160
02/09/17|170
03/09/17|280
```

I am trying to do a division where the first row divides by the second row.

```
Date    |index_numer| Divison by next row
26/08/17|200        | 0.666
27/08/17|300        | 0.75
28/08/17|400        | 4
29/08/17|100        |..
```

I did this in a for loop and then extracted the division number and merge back the DF. however, I am not sure if it can be done in pandas/numpy.

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `shift`:

```
df['divison'] = df['index_numer'] / df['index_numer'].shift(-1)
```

Output:

```
   Date      index_numer   divison
0  26/08/17          200  0.666667
1  27/08/17          300  0.750000
2  28/08/17          400  4.000000
3  29/08/17          100  0.666667
4  30/08/17          150  0.937500
5  01/09/17          160  0.941176
6  02/09/17          170  0.607143
7  03/09/17          280       NaN
```